# Unity project wiped, but folders still in hierarchy

Tags: unity-game-engine

I opened my Unity project and there's nothing in it, just a blank scene. All the folders are there in the hierarchy but nothing is in them. I didn't do anything before opening it, like moving the project folder.

Why has this happened and how do I get my project back?

And just to clarify: I did check my scenes folder, it's empty.

Comment: *"how do I get my project back?"* - Revert any changes from source control.  If you're not *using* source control, this is an important lesson demonstrating its usefulness.

Comment: @David 1) I'm new to unity, 2) this was a small project. It's not catastrophic, but it was for school so this is unfortunate that I probably lost it all. Mostly I just want to know what happened, so I can prevent it in the future.

Comment: Could have been anything, really.  But in all honesty the way to prevent it in the future is to use source control.  It maintains a history of your incremental changes, so any time something breaks (this is an extreme example of something breaking, but it's still just that) then you can roll back to a known working version and try again.

Comment: @David I found the answer. But thank you, I will look into source control in case something worse happens in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: I had to open the project from the "Learn" tab of Unity Hub because it was a tutorial.

(Now I'm wondering how it showed up in the projects folder at all... very misleading.)